# Alfresco new workflow hot deploying

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share, alfresco-webscripts

I developped an alfresco share module that allows user to create and save a new workflow. The new workflow files (model.xml, workflow.xml) are stored in a specific folder in alfresco repository. All works fine. Now to finalize my module, i want add a button in my share module to allows users to hot deploying the new workflow and run it on alfresco without restarting alfresco.

Is there a possibility to achieve this?

I thought to call a java webscript from my module to hot deploying the workflow. Is this possible?

If you have an example to how achieve this, it'll be very helpful for me.

Comment: Do you mean the equivalent of doing `deploy activiti path/to/workflow/bpmn.xml` in the Alfresco workflow console?

Comment: Yes, exactly this. I want do this directly from my new module page without using the workflow console.  Is this possible by using a webscript that i call from my share module when clicking a specific button?

Comment: Without knowing your Alfresco version, can't say if there's a built-in webscript available. It's pretty simple to write your own java backed webscript to do it though

Comment: I'm in version 5.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved my issue.
So to hot deploy workflow into Alfresco, i used Alfresco Java Api services that allowed me to hot deploy the workflow definition. There is a small code t how achieve this.

```
InputStream input = contentService.getReader(new NodeRef("YOUR_WORKFLOW_DEFINITION_FILE_NODEREF"),ContentModel.TYPE_CONTENT).getContentInputStream();
workflowDeployment = workflowService.deployDefinition("activiti",input,MimetypeMap.MIMETYPE_XML);
```